# Load ajax content into div after the existing content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to load the contents of a web page into my existing page, specifically after existing content, not too replace it. I need to do it after the last HR tag in the div i want the content pulled into.

So, the html i have is:

```
<article>
<p>My content</p>
</article>
<hr>
```

So i want my content to load in directly after that `<hr>` tag. But i'm trying to use after, and it's doing something odd with the `<hr>` tag, trying to make it `<hr>`my ajax content`</hr>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.news-ajax-link').click(function(){
    $("article hr").after().load('/news/ajax_news/?offset=2');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: try changing `<hr>` to `<hr/>`. Especially if this is in IE.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `.load()` function is specifically designed to *load content into a container element*, so what it's attempting to do is precisely what you told it to: load the content of that URL inside your `<hr>` element.

If you want to append the content after the `<hr>` you'll need to use one of the other AJAX functions that jQuery provides - I'd suggest using [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - and do the appending yourself inside the callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.news-ajax-link').click(function(event){ // note the event parameter added here
        $.ajax({
            url: '/news/ajax_news/?offset=2',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(content) {
                $("article hr").after(content);
            });
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that looks good to me and doesn't throw up any syntax errors in my text editor. But when i run it it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) " in google chrome

Comment: @bjohnb Odd. Is there other code in your actual page that might be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to close the hr, so use this

```
<hr />
```

otherwise jQuery (or possibly the browser) thinks its an unclosed tag

EDIT: ACTUALLY I think the problem is at after()

after() is mean to have an argument so try this:

```
.after(/*AJAXED content here*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using `.append()` rather than `.after()`.

Or perhaps add in an `html` tag and `load()` into it.

such as

```
<article>
<p>My content</p>
</article>
<hr>
<span id="loadedContent"></span>


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.news-ajax-link').click(function(){
     $("#loadedContent").load('/news/ajax_news/?offset=2');
    event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```